# Making Ridge Line and Valley Line from Contours or DEM using SAGA GIS

Tags: dem, saga, contour

How do I make ridge lines and valley lines using open source GIS Software?

I am totally stuck. I found solution in SAGA GIS - also available in QGIS but it freezes when I run it.
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/ta_morphometry_24.html
I used default settings. I used this method in separate SAGA app and also in QGIS both same issue.

I have DEM 0,25x0,25 in tiff and also countour lines in shp with 1m step.